# Paypal pro credit card payment using username,password, and vendor

Tags: php, paypal

I want to implement credit card payment on my website , i download paypal samples code and i test on sandbox it's working properly but in this code i see username,passsword,and signature but i have only username,password,and vendors i have no signature , can any one know how i m implement credit card direct payment using username,password,and vendor.
I m low in php , please help me asap.

Website Payments Pro Vendor:
Website Payments Pro Username:
Website Payments Pro Password:

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but if you say you are "low in PHP" could you honestly say you have secured your website enough to handle credit card details and are fully [PCI  DSS compliant](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/)?

The username, password and signature are found under the PayPal Profile page under API Credentials, then you want to view the API signature rather than certificate.

**Update**

Take a look at [this document](https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1884) on PayPals developer network. It states

> VENDOR = Merchant Login ID.  This is the lD created when you signed up for your account.
>   USER = Merchant Login ID unless you created a USER for Payflow Pro
>   PWD = Password for VENDOR unless you have a different USER, then it would be for USER.

**Examples:**

*Correct usage:*

VENDOR=myaccount
USER=myaccount
PARTNER=PayPalUK
PWD=mypassword

USER can also be different from VENDOR if you created a user for your transactions.  This is actually suggested.

Example: vendor=myaccount&user=myaccountpro&pwd=myaccountpropassword&partner=mypartner

*Incorrect usages:*

VENDOR=AFnbvsbQVRButJHZs6.l0X3A7qNRAD.JM9YVjurzrVeDxa2ua9NmevLN
USER=bob._1187260083_biz_api1.myweb.com
PARTNER=PayPalUK

VENDOR=paypal_api1.myemail.com
USER=paypal_api1.myemail.com
PARTNER=PayPal

Comment: Thanks @lethalMango , but my client only give me username,password,and vendor , any idea how i m implement using vendor instead of signature.

Comment: @Layric - updated my answer above

Comment: Thanks @lethalMango , i want to download some sample code , can you know any link ?

Comment: Layric, you need to use the Payflow Pro sample code. What you have are credentials for PayPal Payflow Pro (for some time, also available as 'Website Payments Pro UK' or 'Website Payments Pro Payflow Edition'). Payflow Pro uses vendor/user/password/partner authentication, whereas the normal PayPal API's uses user/password/signature or user/password/certificate.